# Merge the values of a melt dataframe and another one

Tags: r

Using a melt dataframe like this:

```
dframe1 <- data.frame <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,2), name = c("google", "google", "amazon"))
```

and a second data frame which has the same id coloumn like this:

```
dframe2 <- data.frame(id = c(1,2), mainnum = c(12.4, 32.1))
```

How is it possible to merge the two dataframes and receive this result:

```
data.frame <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,2), name = c("google", "google", "amazon"), mainnum = c(12.4, 12.4, 32.1))
```

Comment: Just use `merge` `merge(dframe1, dframe2, all = TRUE)`

Comment: Maybe `dplyr`'s `left_join` is your friend.